# Cannot scroll to top with mCustomScrollbar plugin

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar

Hey guys i am using a plugin to scroll to top  and on body of my website i am using the mCustomScrollbar plugin.

The problem is that that for the scrolbar plugin the height should be like this

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0px;
    color: #eee;
    background: #222;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

The height should be set at 100%.

And then using the scroll to top I use this function

```
function goToTop() {
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 1200);
}
```

And the Scroll toTop jquery is

```
// Define the variables
var easing, e, pos;

$(function(){

// Get the click event
$(".go-top-sets li").on("click", function(){

// Get the class
easing= $(this).attr("class");

// Get the scroll pos
pos= $(window).scrollTop();

// Set the body top margin
$("body").css({
  "margin-top": -pos+"px",
  "overflow-y": "scroll", // This property is posed for fix the blink of the window width change 
});

// Make the scroll handle on the position 0
$(window).scrollTop(0);

// Get the easing
switch(easing){
  case "easing-1":
    e= "cubic-bezier(0.600, 0.040, 0.980, 0.335)";
    break;
  case "easing-2":
    e= "cubic-bezier(1.000, -0.560, 0.000, 1.455)";
    break;
  case "easing-3":
    e= "cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275)";
    break;
}

// Add the transition property to the body element
$("#ponyBody").css("transition", "all 1s " + e);

// Apply the scroll effects
$("#ponyBody").css("margin-top", "0");

// Wait until the transition end
$("#ponyBody").on("webkitTransitionEnd transitionend msTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd", function () {
  // Remove the transition property
    $("#ponyBody").css("transition", "none");
});
});

});
```

**When i remove the 100% on height the scroll To Top works fine but the scrollbar is very small and content.
Please help.**
thanks